# Google Cloud Architecture - Project setup for multiple regions

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, architecture, cloud

I am trying to startup a team which requires resources to be deployed in 3 cloud regions which are to be isolated from each other.
Currently we have 2 environments - dev & prod, so the plan is to have 2 GCP projects - 1 for dev and 1 for prod(Each containing the 3 regions).

From what I understand in GCP, you can have all 3 regions in the same project and VPC(as VPCs are global) and therefore just have this one 1 VPC in each project. The current plan for the architecture is to just deploy the serverless applications to their specific regions. However when I looked into it more, it seems that having all 3 regions resources in the same project and VPC would make it less isolated than the other proposed solution of having 3 dev project, and 3 prod projects(i.e 1 region per project per environment).

I couldn't find anything detailing what the best practises were for this kind of scenario so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what do you want to isolate. Serverless services are isolated by default (it's container with independent identity and access management).

In term of VPC, you can keep 1 project but create 3 VPC in the same project, 1 per region. You will be isolated at network level.

But, even if your VPCs are isolated, the accounts (users or service) can access to all the VPCs of the project (if you are a compute Admin user, you can create a VM, whatever the VPC). If you need more isolation, you have to create different project to give permissions only to the correct region to the accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your great reply. I had thought about creating 3 different VPCs in the same project - each with 1 region, but then I don't see the big deal/advantage about VPCs being global in GCP if you can't isolate the regional resources.. Hence why I figured it would be best to have 1 global VPC, but have 3 subnets. However when I was looking into this, I didn't realise that serverless services (like buckets, functions, cloud run) aren't even deployed in a subnet in your VPC, they are just deployed into the region. 

----reply extended below-----

Comment: Therefore you can't do as much network isolation configuration(firewalls etc) between these different region resources as they aren't in the VPCs subnet.
Ok...I guess my main concern around isolation is trying to prevent accidentally sending data from a resource in 1 region, to a resource in a different region. I guess what I'm asking is ....What the best solution in terms of Project, VPC setup for a prod environment to prevent the following:  "a cloud functions script moving data from a bucket in us-central1 region to a bucket in asia-southeast2"

Comment: Yes Firewall rules can also apply between the ranges in the different regions. To prevent data movement, you can also set VPC SC (Service Control), but it's boring to configure. Before, clearly define what you want to do and against what you what to be protected.

Comment: Ok but how can I use firewall rules to do network isolation, if I'm deploying serverless services like cloud functions, cloud run which aren't actually deploy inside of a VPC? They just sit outside of the VPC, but in the region specified

Comment: If you are using serverless product, you can't restrict the regional use. That's why project segregation is a better (the only one) solution